# MySQL: Prepare/Execute in procedure (concat)

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

i'm abit lost and i'm hoping for your help. I'm currently learning to work with Mysql and i got this procedure:

```
delimiter //
drop procedure price_update2 //
create procedure price_update2()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT default 0;
DECLARE i INT default 1;
DECLARE cond varchar(255) default '';

SET cond = CONCAT('SELECT customer_id FROM customers LIMIT ',i,',1');
prepare stt FROM cond;
execute stt;
END //
```

for some reason i always get an error near the "cond; execute stt....". Probably it's just an easy thing, but i can't find it.
Also tried without concat:

```
delimiter //
drop procedure price_update2 //
create procedure price_update2()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT default 0;
DECLARE i INT default 1;
DECLARE cond varchar(255) default '';

SET cond = 'SELECT customer_id FROM customers LIMIT 1';
prepare stt FROM cond;
execute stt;
END //
```

if i use the statement directly, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an odd thing, but you need to use [user-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) at this point:

```
delimiter //
drop procedure price_update2 //
create procedure price_update2()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT default 0;
DECLARE i INT default 1;

SET @cond = CONCAT('SELECT customer_id FROM customers LIMIT ',i,',1');
prepare stt FROM @cond;
execute stt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stt; # don't forget to deallocate
END //
```

The [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html) states this:

> A statement prepared in stored program context cannot refer to stored procedure or function parameters or local variables because they go out of scope when the program ends and would be unavailable were the statement to be executed later outside the program. As a workaround, refer instead to user-defined variables, which also have session scope

Comment: Thank you very much! I totally overread this, thinking "@.." is just another way people use to clarify 'their' variables :) U rock!

Comment: Another note: a `limit` without an `order by` is quite meaningless. Relational databases are based on set theory.

Comment: Yes, i stumbled across that a minute ago :) Thanks!